# Will a Microsoft Office Add-In developed in Visual Studio work for both a Windows and Mac ( osx ) versions of Ms Office?

Tags: macos, windows, ms-office, development, compatibility

I want to develop a Microsoft Office Word Add-In for Mac Users. I would like to know if we create it using Visual Studios in windows will it be compatible with the Mac version of office or is there a whole another way to develop for Mac?

Please provide links so that I could follow some guidelines. The http://msdn.microsoft.com/ site doesn't exactly speak of the platform compatibility of the Add-In.

Thank You very Much in Advance.

Comment: How do you create a n Office Add in, please provide more info than just using VS

Comment: In Visual Studios using the template provide by default to make Add-ins for Ms Office using C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Office:Mac 2011 only supports add-ins that were developed in VBA.  Office:Mac 2008 does not support add-ins at all.  A [new version of Office:Mac is slated for release in 2015](http://www.macworld.com/article/2842020/microsoft-says-new-office-for-mac-due-in-2015-unveils-new-outlook-app.html), there have been no announcements as of this writing (December 2014) whether Microsoft will support additional methods of developing add-ins in the new version of Office:Mac.

For further information, check out [Getting Started with VBA in Office for Mac 2011](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Getting-Started-with-VBA-in-Office-for-Mac-2011-f75c9aaf-74d2-46a5-a24a-c19d81a14b29?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US) from the Office:Mac 2011 help files.  You might find more assistance in developing Office:Mac add-ins in the [Office:Mac help forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mac/forum/macoffice2011?tab=Threads) hosted by Microsoft.

Comment: The VS c# adding run on the .NET virtual machine which MS do not supply for OS X, so they cannot run. MS have made part of .NET open source and so future versions of adding might run in OS X